# IIS/ASP.NET not finding my Web App binaries

Tags: asp.net, iis

IIS 10.0 under Windows 10 Pro.  ASP.NET 4.7

Please consider this a newbie question -- it's been a while since I've worked with IIS.

I'm researching some issues that only seem to occur running under IIS (versus running the website in Visual Studio 2017).  So, I installed IIS 10.0 on my Windows development computer and published my website to IIS.  The error described below is NOT the one I'm researching, but a roadblock in trying to get my website setup on my local IIS.

When I try to access the "home" page, I get a Parser Error.

> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'WingtipToys.Global'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs"
>   Inherits="WingtipToys.Global" Language="C#" %>
>
> Source File: /global.asax    Line: 1

(I also tried running Microsoft's Wingtip Toys sample website and I'm getting the same error as with my website.  Showing Wingtip Toys error above.)

There is a BIN folder in my application (as installed in IIS), there is a WingtipToys.dll in that folder, and (according to .NET Reflector) there is a WingtipToys.Global class in the DLL.

I had thought ASP.NET would look for the BIN folder and use any DLLs it finds there.

As both the Wingtip Toys and my websites show the same error under IIS and both run fine in VS 2017, I suspect this may be an IIS or ASP.NET configuration error on my part.

What do I need to do to allow IIS/ASP.NET to find the binaries in my BIN folder?  One suggestion I found was to put the following in my website web.config:

```
  <system.web>
      <compilation targetFramework="4.5">
          <assemblies>
              <add assembly="*" />
          </assemblies>
      </compilation>
  </system.web>
```

While that works, we apparently don't need it on our production website (the one I'm trying to troubleshoot).  (Plus, our production web.config has about 40 assemblies which are ALL in the website BIN folder.  That seems to me redundant.)

I must be missing something.

If you have any questions, please let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: Is there a WingtipToys.dll in the GAC?   Maybe its loading an old version??

Comment: I didn't see WingtipToys.dll (nor my website DLL) in the GAC.  Just the standard stuff -- pretty much.  Thx!

Comment: I'd probably use Fusion Logs and see if I see anythign unexpected: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer

Comment: I used the Fusion Log viewer (I've used this tool several times in the past), but did not find any binding errors.  I checked for both successful and failed bindings, restarting IIS before each attempt.  All the successful bindings are for standard System/Microsoft assemblies; there were no failed bindings.  I'm not seeing any attempted binding to the WingtipToys.dll.  It may be the process failed before any attempted binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I figured, there was something missing from my IIS configuration.  My original web app and the other sample web apps I used to test this were compiled as "Any CPU".  In IIS, each of the application pools I used for these apps had "Enable 32-bit Applications" (under Advanced Settings) set to False.  Once I set each one to True, all of the web apps worked as expected.

I no longer needed the "add assembly=*" workaround -- it looked like ASP.NET was finding what it needed in the BIN folder again.  There was also an additional error of ASP.NET not finding the build provider for ASPX files.  This additional error also disappeared.

Hope this helps someone in the future.  Thanks for the replies!